# Runtime error 462 in regard to MSForms.DataObject

Tags: excel, vba, ms-word

I have built a script with the help of which the contents from form fields of several Word documents are to be read out one after the other and transferred to a common Excel table. The copy functions themselves work and the data of the first Word file are also transferred correctly, but runtime error 462 occurs with the second Word file.
I have already learned that this is related to the object relationships to the Word document. When the first Word document is closed, my objects are apparently destroyed and can no longer be called up correctly in the second file.
In particular, the problem seems to be related to the MSForms.DataObject. I have already read how to work around the error for the objects with a direct Word reference by calling the object again, but I don't know how to do that for the MSForms object.
Does anyone have any advice?
I have pasted the relevant code from my script below.
If this looks like a bad code, it's because I'm not a programmer and had to Google the relevant VBA knowledge. I just want it to run.

If you ask why I use the MSForms object -> I need it to get rid of paragraphs and similar stuff that people might enter in the form fields so I can squeeze all information from one form field to one cell in Excel.

The references to word and MSForms are also set.

```
Sub DatenProduktion()

'Variablen definieren

'Definitionen fuer Suchpfad
Dim sPfad As String
Dim sOrdner As Integer
Dim strOrd As String
Dim sDateiPr As String
Dim vDateiPr As String
Dim vollPfadPr As String

'Definitionen fuer Zielzellen
Dim startzeile As Integer
Dim startzeilePF As Integer 'Dient zur Bestimmung der ersten Nummer der Maengelberichte
Dim sSpalte As Integer
Dim sZeile As Integer
Dim eSpalte As Integer
Dim eZeile As Integer

'Variablen fuer Uebertragung Inhalte
Dim strDateiPr As String
Dim origstr As String
Dim cleanstr As String
Dim corrstr As String
Dim checkbx As String
Dim clipbrd As MSForms.DataObject

'Variablen fuer Oeffnung Word
Dim wordApp As Word.Application
Dim wDoc As Word.Document


'___________________________________
'Erste freie Zeile finden

Workbooks("Mangelauswertung.xlsm").Worksheets("Produktion").Activate

startzeile = WorksheetFunction.CountA(Range("A:A")) + 4 
'___________________________________
'Erste Zielzeile in Produktion
eZeile = startzeile
startzeilePF = startzeile - 5
'___________________________________


'Loop beginnen
Do

'Zuruecksetzen Spalte
eSpalte = 1


'Pfad zur erste noch nicht eingepflegten Word konstruieren
sPfad = "P:\Mängelbericht\Mängelberichte Word\"
sOrdner = startzeilePF
sDateiPr = "Mängelbericht Produktion.docx"
strOrd = CStr(sOrdner)
vollPfadPr = sPfad & strOrd & "_" & sDateiPr
'___________________________________

If Dir(vollPfadPr) <> "" Then

    'Namen der Datei in erste Spalte schreiben
    vDateiPr = strOrd & "_" & sDateiPr
    Workbooks("Mangelauswertung.xlsm").Worksheets("Produktion").Cells(eZeile, eSpalte) = vDateiPr
    eSpalte = eSpalte + 1


    'Word Datei oeffnen
    Set wordApp = CreateObject("word.application")
    Set wDoc = wordApp.Documents.Open(vollPfadPr)
    wordApp.Visible = True
    Set clipbrd = New MSForms.DataObject
    
    'Artikelbezeichnung
    wDoc.Bookmarks("Artikelbezeichnung").Range.Copy
    clipbrd.GetFromClipboard
    origstr = clipbrd.GetText(1)
    cleanstr = CleanString(origstr)
    corrstr = Replace(cleanstr, Chr(13), Chr(32))
    Workbooks("Mangelauswertung.xlsm").Worksheets("Produktion").Cells(eZeile, eSpalte) = corrstr
    eSpalte = eSpalte + 1

    [...]

    'Word-Datei schliessen
    Set clipbrd = Nothing
    wordApp.Documents.Close
    wordApp.Quit
    Set wordApp = Nothing
    Set wDoc = Nothing

'___________________________________
'Falls keine (neue) Datei gefunden werden kann
Else
    Workbooks("Mangelauswertung.xlsm").Worksheets("Produktion").Protect Password:="*****"
    Exit Do
End If

eZeile = eZeile + 1
startzeilePF = startzeilePF + 1

Loop

[...]

End Sub
```

Comment: See: https://www.msofficeforums.com/word-vba/19914-how-transferring-word-data-excel-sheet.html, https://www.msofficeforums.com/word-vba/27552-extracting-data-word-documents.html, etc.

Comment: As far as I understand the makros you linked, they wouldn't work in my case. When I just copy the range from the form field that contains a paragraph within the text, it gets pasted in Excel in several cells. That's unacceptable for me. I have to modify the string before it gets pasted to Excel. That's why I need the MSForms.DataObject and I need to understand why it's broken in my case.

Comment: What those two links demonstrate is that you don't need to address each bookmark and there is no need to use the clipboard. For example: `origstr = wDoc.Bookmarks("Artikelbezeichnung").Range.Text` will give you the same as `origstr = clipbrd.GetText(1)`

Comment: I tried ```origstr = wDoc.Bookmarks("Artikelbezeichnung").Range.Text``` but I still get the same runtime error on the line ```cleanstr = CleanString(origstr)```. I guess my objects don't get a proper reset for the second word file, but I don't understand why. I copied the parts to close the word file and set them to nothing from another script on Stackoverflow which seemed to work.

Comment: If the Word formfield contains multiple paragraphs, you have to manipulate the data before inserting it into Excel. See my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to use the MSForms.DataObject, the clipboard, or to reference any bookmarks. Try the following macro, which is coded to process both formfields and content controls:

```
Sub GetFormData()
'Note: this code requires a reference to the Word object model.
'See under the VBE's Tools|References.
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Dim strFolder As String, strFile As String
Dim WkSht As Worksheet, i As Long, j As Long
strFolder = GetFolder
If strFolder = "" Then Exit Sub
Dim wdApp As New Word.Application, wdDoc As Word.Document
Dim FmFld As Word.FormField, CCtrl As Word.ContentControl
Set WkSht = ActiveSheet
i = WkSht.Cells(WkSht.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
'Disable any auto macros in the documents being processed
wdApp.WordBasic.DisableAutoMacros
strFile = Dir(strFolder & "\*.doc", vbNormal)
While strFile <> ""
  i = i + 1
  Set wdDoc = wdApp.Documents.Open(Filename:=strFolder & "\" & strFile, AddToRecentFiles:=False, Visible:=False)
  With wdDoc
    j = 0
    For Each FmFld In .FormFields
      j = j + 1
      With FmFld
        Select Case .Type
          Case Is = wdFieldFormCheckBox
            WkSht.Cells(i, j) = .CheckBox.Value
          Case Else
            If IsNumeric(FmFld.Result) Then
              If Len(FmFld.Result) > 15 Then
                WkSht.Cells(i, j) = "'" & FmFld.Result
              Else
                WkSht.Cells(i, j) = FmFld.Result
              End If
            Else
              WkSht.Cells(i, j) = Replace(Replace(FmFld.Result, vbCr, "¶"), Chr(11), "¶")
            End If
        End Select
      End With
    Next
    For Each CCtrl In .ContentControls
      With CCtrl
        Select Case .Type
          Case Is = wdContentControlCheckBox
            j = j + 1
            WkSht.Cells(i, j) = .Checked
          Case wdContentControlDate, wdContentControlDropdownList, wdContentControlRichText, wdContentControlText
            j = j + 1
            If IsNumeric(.Range.Text) Then
              If Len(.Range.Text) > 15 Then
                WkSht.Cells(i, j).Value = "'" & .Range.Text
              Else
                WkSht.Cells(i, j).Value = .Range.Text
              End If
            Else
              WkSht.Cells(i, j) = Replace(Replace(.Range.Text, vbCr, "¶"), Chr(11), "¶")
            End If
          Case Else
        End Select
      End With
    Next
    .Close SaveChanges:=False
  End With
  strFile = Dir()
Wend
wdApp.Quit
WkSht.UsedRange.Replace What:="¶", Replacement:=Chr(10), LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows
Set wdDoc = Nothing: Set wdApp = Nothing: Set WkSht = Nothing
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
 
Function GetFolder() As String
    Dim oFolder As Object
    GetFolder = ""
    Set oFolder = CreateObject("Shell.Application").BrowseForFolder(0, "Choose a folder", 0)
    If (Not oFolder Is Nothing) Then GetFolder = oFolder.Items.Item.Path
    Set oFolder = Nothing
End Function
```

If you want to record the document's name as part of the data, change:

```
j = 0
```

to:

```
j = 1: WkSht.Cells(i, j) = strFile
```

Comment: This mostly works. There is a strange behaviour that the data isn't pasted in the first empty row but in the first row that hasn't been used before. I guess if I read that code closely enough I should be able to fix that. Also are paragraphs from texts not removed but also transfered to Excel, but this should be easily corrected as well. This code doesn't cause a runtime error on every second try. Thanks a lot.

Comment: As coded, the macro leaves the 1st row in the destination worksheet empty - so you can add headings to it. Otherwise, it starts populating at the first unused row. Unlike Rich's code, mine explicitly creates its own Word session, which it terminates when done.

Answer (score 0):

I’ve edited your code to include a check if Word is already open and using its instance versus creating a new instance in each iteration of your checking the directory for a new Word document. I also moved this out of the loop.

The clipboard is not needed for this routine, you can get the content of the bookmarked range and assign it directly to a string variable.

Finally, I moved the Quit of Word to the end as well as the clearing of the object variables for Word.

```
Option Explicit
Sub DatenProduktion()

'Variablen definieren

'Definitionen fuer Suchpfad
Dim sPfad As String
Dim sOrdner As Integer
Dim strOrd As String
Dim sDateiPr As String
Dim vDateiPr As String
Dim vollPfadPr As String

'Definitionen fuer Zielzellen
Dim startzeile As Integer
Dim startzeilePF As Integer 'Dient zur Bestimmung der ersten Nummer der Maengelberichte
Dim sSpalte As Integer
Dim sZeile As Integer
Dim eSpalte As Integer
Dim eZeile As Integer

'Variablen fuer Uebertragung Inhalte
Dim strDateiPr As String
Dim origstr As String
Dim cleanstr As String
Dim corrstr As String
Dim checkbx As String
'Dim clipbrd As MSForms.DataObject

'Variablen fuer Oeffnung Word
Dim wordApp As Word.Application
Dim wDoc As Word.Document


'___________________________________
'Erste freie Zeile finden

Workbooks("Mangelauswertung.xlsm").Worksheets("Produktion").Activate

startzeile = WorksheetFunction.CountA(Range("A:A")) + 4
'___________________________________
'Erste Zielzeile in Produktion
eZeile = startzeile
startzeilePF = startzeile - 5
'___________________________________


'Loop beginnen
Do

'Zuruecksetzen Spalte
eSpalte = 1


'Pfad zur erste noch nicht eingepflegten Word konstruieren
sPfad = "P:\Mängelbericht\Mängelberichte Word\"
sOrdner = startzeilePF
sDateiPr = "Mängelbericht Produktion.docx"
strOrd = CStr(sOrdner)
vollPfadPr = sPfad & strOrd & "_" & sDateiPr
'___________________________________

On Error Resume Next
Set wordApp = GetObject(, "Word.Application")
If Err.Number <> 0 Then
    Err.Clear
    Set wordApp = CreateObject("word.application")
End If
wordApp.Visible = True
On Error GoTo 0

If Dir(vollPfadPr) <> "" Then

    'Namen der Datei in erste Spalte schreiben
    vDateiPr = strOrd & "_" & sDateiPr
    Workbooks("Mangelauswertung.xlsm").Worksheets("Produktion").Cells(eZeile, eSpalte) = vDateiPr
    eSpalte = eSpalte + 1


    'Word Datei oeffnen
'    Set wordApp = CreateObject("word.application")
    Set wDoc = wordApp.Documents.Open(vollPfadPr)
'    wordApp.Visible = True
'    Set clipbrd = New MSForms.DataObject
    
    'Artikelbezeichnung
    origstr = wDoc.Bookmarks("Artikelbezeichnung").Range.Text
'    clipbrd.GetFromClipboard
'    origstr = clipbrd.GetText(1)
    cleanstr = CleanString(origstr)
    corrstr = Replace(cleanstr, Chr(13), Chr(32))
    Workbooks("Mangelauswertung.xlsm").Worksheets("Produktion").Cells(eZeile, eSpalte) = corrstr
    eSpalte = eSpalte + 1

    [...]

    'Word-Datei schliessen
'    Set clipbrd = Nothing
    wordApp.Documents.Close
'    wordApp.Quit
'    Set wordApp = Nothing
'    Set wDoc = Nothing

'___________________________________
'Falls keine (neue) Datei gefunden werden kann
Else
    Workbooks("Mangelauswertung.xlsm").Worksheets("Produktion").Protect Password:="*****"
    Exit Do
End If

eZeile = eZeile + 1
startzeilePF = startzeilePF + 1

Loop

wordApp.Quit
If Not wordApp = Nothing Then Set wordApp = Nothing
If Not wDoc = Nothing Then Set wDoc = Nothing


[...]

End Sub
```

Comment: This does seem to do the trick. However if I try to run this with the 2 lines ```If Not wordApp = Nothing Then Set wordApp = Nothing
If Not wDoc = Nothing Then Set wDoc = Nothing``` Excel pops up an error message that should roughly be translated to "Error during compilation: Invalid use of an object". So I took those 2 lines out of the script and it worked... basically. On the first try running this, it worked (with 13 files), but on every second try the script stops with the runtime error 462. On the third try after the error it works again. Any guess why?

Comment: Change this command wordApp.Documents.Close to wDoc.Close. I think that will fix the issue. The other error on clearing the wordApp and wDoc objects is my error they should read, If Not wordApp Is Nothing then ...

Comment: I made the changes you described, but the runtime error on every second run of the script still occures. Anyway I thank you a lot.